# on click display large image

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

Hi there are lot of topics about this but i still cant figure it out for my example.
I've got thumbnails in /thumbnails folder and large images in /image folder all numbered from 1-50. When i click on specific thumbnail a want large image with same number shown on screen (which is my main problem) 
My html code looks like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail-box"><img src="thumbs/1.jpg" class="thumbs"></div>
<div class="thumbnail-box"><img src="thumbs/2.jpg" class="thumbs"></div>
<div class="thumbnail-box"><img src="thumbs/3.jpg" class="thumbs"></div>
...
```

Maybe i need some if code to check which number of thumnail it is and then use that number for an image. If anyone can help i will be really gratefull

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` to update `src` attribute of image.

```
$('.thumbnail-box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumbs', 'image'));
});
```

This will change the image `src` from `thumbs/1.jpg` to `image/1.jpg`.

You might also want to **remove class**:

```
$(this).removeClass('thumbnail-box');
```

Comment: this will just replace thumbnail for picture. but i actually needs to open a new div with enlarged picture in it. Maybe if i gave every picture different "id" would it be easier?